# Installings Maps and YouTube on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone

I installed the iPhone Simulator 3.0. I am not using it for iPhone app development, but rather for web development.

I want to pull up some of my web apps in Mobile Safari and take video screencasts in order to demo them to those without iPhones.

Some of these web apps use the Maps and YouTube apps, which are standard on the iPhone, but not on the iPhone Simulator.

Is there any way to download/install these and other standard apps?

Comment: Disagreed. The user may not be strictly programming, but there are plenty of programmers whose iPhone apps may send their users off to YouTube or Maps who'd need to test the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install these apps on the simulator, you are going to have to test on the device instead.